# Reading and writing memory, but having trouble writing to a virtual address

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I am trying to write a program where I scan a processes memory and can also write to these addresses(just like cheat engine). However I did some research and found out that the memory I was reading is virtual memory I can read this memory but I can't write to it and to translate it I need page tables. So my question is where can I find these page tables and is there any other way to write using the virtual address I get?

Comment: A program running in "user space" cannot to this kind of thing.  What operating system are you talking about?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/virtual-and-physical-memory#physical-memory ... physical memory (which is where the page tables are) is only accessible in kernel debugging mode.   But if it is possible, these are deep and dangerous waters.

Comment: (I'm puzzled why you need to access the page tables to read the memory of a process.  A processes memory is >virtual< memory. You don't need to go down to the physical level to read or write it.)

Comment: @StephenC I can read from the virtual address, however when I try to write to it using the writeprocessmemory function it doesn't work

Comment: Ah.  This is X-Y problem!  You are trying to solve the problem that `writeprocessmemory` is not working for you.  Well ... delving into to the page tables and physical RAM is not the way to solve that.  If something (e.g. security) is stopping you from writing to another processes RAM, then you shouldn't be able to do an "end run" around that using the page tables, etc.

Comment: Note that the docs for `writeprocessmemory` states: *"The entire area to be written to must be accessible or the operation fails."*.  That is most likely the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory is an elaborate illusion. What you think is read/write RAM may actually be data in swap space, or "ready only, copy on write", or something else.

To maintain the illusion, and for security, and for compatibility (e.g. 32-bit program running on a 64-bit CPU with a 64-bit kernel); user-space is not given access to page tables.

An OS or kernel might provide an abstract interface to some of the information (with suitable restrictions and limitations for security). One example of this would be the `VirtualQuery()` and `VirtualQueryEx()` functions in Windows (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex ).

In a similar way, an OS or kernel might provide an abstract interface to alter a page's permissions (with suitable restrictions and limitations for security). One example of this would be the `VirtualProtect()` function in Windows (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect ).

> ... and is there any other way to write using the virtual address I get?

If your CPU is an 80x86 CPU that supports Intel's transactional extensions; you can misuse "transactions" to suppress page faults (make them cause a "transaction abort" instead of triggering a page fault).

This won't allow you to write to a read-only or "not present" page; but will allow you to attempt to write without being detected by the OS.